# Parenthetical statements and pronouns

Tags: writing-style, phrase-usage

What's correct/more common way of including them?

Like this:

> This reminded me of the Genesis, the part where God, after finding out
>   **Eve** gave the apple to Adam, He says to the **her**: "... with painful
>   labor you will give birth to children."

Or like this:

> This reminded me of the Genesis, the part where God, after finding out
>   **she** gave the apple to Adam, He says to the **Eve**: "... with painful
>   labor you will give birth to children."

Comment: I think you have a cut & paste error here.  You would never refer to "the Eve" as you have in your second quote.

Comment: You also wouldn't say _the her_ in the first version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This reminded me of the Genesis, the part where God, after finding out Eve gave the apple to Adam, says to her: "... with painful labor you will give birth to children."**

Reason:

I was always taught that the personal pronoun "she" comes after the first occurrence of the noun it points to, not the other way around.

(Note also the removal of the extra "He". Otherwise, leaving out the bit between the parenthetical commas, you'd have "This reminded me of the Genesis, the part where God, He says to her: '... with painful labor you will give birth to children.'" In writing, "God says to her" is better than "God, He says to her" unless you're being colloquial for effect.)

Also consider "Genesis" instead of "the Genesis", unless the latter is common phrasing in your academic/faith community.

Answer (score 1):

While both are grammatical, it's easier to read if the pronoun is used after the person is named, as in the first version. When you're scanning the second version, and come across the pronoun *she*, your mind will automatically try to determine the antecedent, and consider what has gone before, not realizing that the answer is forthcoming. This will slow down the reading.

The word *antecedent* even suggests this, as the prefix *ante-* means *before*.

[Grammarist](http://grammarist.com/grammar/pronouns/) has some discussion of this:

> ### Pronoun placement
>
> ---
>
> In general, a pronoun should follow the word it refers to. When a pronoun precedes its antecedent in a sentence, it leaves the pronoun’s referent up in the air for a moment, which can be disconcerting for the reader. However, there are exceptions in which using a pronoun first can work.

The examples of exceptions that they give mostly have the pronoun in subordinate clauses. But [Language Log](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/001159.html) has an article about putting the antecedent is in the subordinate clause, e.g.

> His foreign critics need to notice that George Bush has now done what they want.

In practically all these cases, the sentences can be reworded to put the antecedent first; putting the pronoun first may be done for stylistic reasons, I suspect.